# Обработать заблокированные сигналы

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, сигналы-слоты

Существует ли способ временно заблокировать приём сигналов у объекта с тем, чтобы потом, при разблокировке, последовательно (впрочем, это не принципиально) их обработать?

(при этом сам объект, для которого требуется блокировка, работает в отдельном потоке)

Comment: Блокировка и накопление в очереди - это немножечко разные задачи. Похоже на [проблему xy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy) или плохой дизайн

Comment: У меня не так много опыта в многопоточности, так что моё решение действительно может быть далеко не самым разумным. В моём потоке есть критические секции работы с файлами (в большом количестве), а также опция преждевременно завершить выполнение потока. Собственно, мне показалось хорошей идеей написать слот stopWorking(), который бы корректно завершал поток тогда, когда гарантированно не открыты никакие файлы. Поэтому я и захотел блокировать сигналы перед открытием файла и обрабатывать их по его закрытию

Comment: Пока объект выполняет слот, он накапливает другие сигналы в очереди. Вас это устраивает?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, вы предлагаете вынести работу в критических секциях в слоты, чтобы их выполнение не могло быть прервано приходом новых сигналов. Да, кажется, это именно то, что мне нужно, спасибо

Comment: Тогда сразу вопрос, зачем там критические секции. Это совсем не тот примитив синхронизации, когда речь идет о работе с файлами. (Есть еще вопрос, откуда вообще появилась необходимость вешать на файлы блокировки - уж не велосипедите ли вы СУБД)

Comment: Ну, опять же, да, возможно, я чего-то не понимаю. Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы по нажатию кнопки "Отмена" прерывалось выполнение потока. terminate(), как я понимаю, мне совершенно не подходит, как и wait() (который просто будет дожидаться завершение run()). Мне нужно послать сигнал потоку, чтобы он уже самостоятельно корректно сам себя завершил. Конечно, это можно решить специальным флагом, но, я думаю, это будет не самым изящным с точки зрения кода решением (впрочем, могу ошибаться)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136570/discussion-between-gbg-and-grub-666).